# How to avoid code copying in this class hierarchy?

Tags: c++, inheritance, static

I have the following class hierarchy, in which the instantiation of class B has to be static in both child classes:

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
protected:
  virtual int get_num() const=0;
};

class B {
  int num;
public:
  int get_num() {
    return num=2;
  }
};

class D1 : public A { 
public:
  static B b;
  int get_num() const override {
    return b.get_num();
  }
};
B D1::b;

class D2 : public A {
public:
  static B b;
  int get_num() const override {
    return b.get_num();
  }
};
B D2::b;

int main() {
  D1 d1;
  std::cout << d1.get_num() << std::endl;
  D2 d2;
  std::cout << d2.get_num() << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

My problem is that the definitions of the getter functions in the children classes are CTRL+C CTRL+V copies of each other, which should be avoided because they do exactly the same and they might be lengthy. I am looking for a possible workaround, is there a better practice in such a case? Is this a code smell and a sign of bad design?

**Edit:**
Classes D1 and D2 (and all their derived classes) can do different things, but the point is that the objects of the classes of each branch in the hierarchy have to work on the same instantiation of B (that's why it is declared as static). Otherwise, B could be instantiated in A. The problem is that the functions (which do the same and could be defined in A in the latter case) in the lack of instantiation of B in A, have to be defined in D1 and D2.

Comment: Most likely you would extract another base class from which both `D1` and `D2` would inherit. But it's not very clear what is the actualy use case, so it's hard to propose solutions.

Comment: `class A` (or some other base class) could have a `B& get_b();`.  Then some base class can have one common `int get_num() { return get_b().get_num(); }`

Comment: It's not quite clear why you need to use 2 child classes to do the same?

Comment: @DrewDormann In that case, if I understand correctly, the only code repetition would be the definition of B& get_b(); in each of the derived classes.

Comment: @curious_amateur no, there is no need for the derived classes to know about B.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Can explain it please? The static objects of B are defined in D1 and D2.

Comment: Hmm static objects. Do they need to be static? Do they need to be different objects for `D1` and `D2`?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Yes, that is my problem. I would like all the instantiations of D1 to work on the same instantiation of B. The same stands for D2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have several classes that all have a B member and delegate some functionality to it, you should extract this bit into a common base class.

If it is not a static member you would do just this:

```
class Awith B : public A
{
  public: 
    int get_num() override {
     return b.get_num();
    }       
  private:
     B b;
};
```

Now your `D1` and `D2` can inherit `AwithB` without even knowing that `B` exists.

If they do need to know about `B` for some other reason, just change `private:` to `protected:`.

Now if the `B` object should be static, and each derived class should have its own separate instance, this is a bit trickier, but not by much.

```
template <typename Derived>
class AwithB : public A {
   ...
   static inline B b;
};

class D1 : public AwithB<D1> { ... };
class D2 : public AwithB<D2> { ... };
```

Here we use CRTP to inject the derived class *identity* to the base. Different derived classes derive from different specializations of `AwithB`, so each has its own static member.

Comment: Great solution, I was not aware of this inline keyword in C++17.